# generate targets in makefile depending on input text file

Tags: makefile, vhdl

I'm new here and at using makefiles.
I have a question please:

I had3 tests to execute:

I added manually test1, test2 and test3 as targets in my make file like this:

```
test1: compile_design
 compile test1_testname.vhd >> log_file.log
 simulate test1_testname
```

I did the samething for test2 and 3.

also I added

```
all : test1 test2 test3
```

This works wonderfully.

Now, I want to make this makefile more portable: 
from an input file which contains the following information:

```
test1_testname
test2_testname
test3_testname
```

I want the 3 targets to be added automatically
and in general n targets if the input file contains n lines.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to use a source file. It may be easier to list your targets at the top of the Makefile. Then, by using pattern rules, you can have what you want with the following.

```
TESTS=test1_testname test2_testname test3_testname

all: $(TESTS)

%_testname: compile_design
    compile $@.vhd >> log_file.log
    simulate $@
```

You can note that the pattern rule defines targets as `test1_testname` instead of the shorter `test1`. This is to avoid having a `%` pattern rule.

If you really want to use another file to list your targets, you can change the first line with

```
TESTS=$(shell cat yoursourcefile)
```

Comment: Thanks.
But normally test_name is different for each test.
Thst's why I need to make targets name shorter:
Is there any way to generate them like:
testX: compile_design
    compile $@.vhd >> log_file.log
    simulate $@ 
with X from 0 to test_number (to get from the file line number)

also I need an input file because test number will be different from one project to another.

I hope there is a way to do this.

Comment: Note that even if the names are different, it can work using the `%` target as in `%: compile_design`. Furthermore, `$@` in the commands will automatically be replaced by the target name, i.e. the current test name.

Comment: I used
`%: compile design
    compile $@.vhd >> log_file.log
    simulate $@

`
but I got makefile_tb.vhd >> log_file.log
as if makefile is a target